# How to get Metadata from a Token adress using web3 js on SOLANA

Tags: reactjs, jsx, token, solana, solana-web3js

I get a list of tokens own by a publicKey thanks to that method :

```
connection
.getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner(
  new PublicKey(publicKey.toBase58()),
  {
    programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
  }
)
.then((b) => {
  const owner = b?.value?.[0].account.owner;
  const pb = b?.value?.[0].pubkey;

  const nonZeroAccounts = b?.value?.filter(
    (obj) => obj.account.data.parsed.info.tokenAmount.uiAmount > 0
  );
  setTokens(JSON.stringify(nonZeroAccounts, null, 2));
```

return value for an account that own 1 token for example :

```
{
"account": {
  "data": {
    "parsed": {
      "info": {
        "isNative": false,
        "mint": "example",
        "owner": "example",
        "state": "initialized",
        "tokenAmount": {
          "amount": "1",
          "decimals": 0,
          "uiAmount": 1,
          "uiAmountString": "1"
        }
      },
      "type": "account"
    },
    "program": "spl-token",
    "space": 165
  },
  "executable": false,
  "lamports": 2039280,
  "owner": {
    "_bn": "example"
  },
  "rentEpoch": 245
},
"pubkey": {
  "_bn": "example"
}
```

Now that I have these informations, I would like to know how to get the metadata of that token

Comment: Sweet the 12.18.2021 solution worked for me. You should make this the answer so perhaps google search can index it. The metaplex doc example does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After Soubriquet request, I ll add here the actual working code.

Metaplex doc isnt always up to date, so don't trust it.

```
    const Metadata = require("@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata");
    
    async function getMetadataPDA(mint) 
        {
          const [publicKey] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
            [Buffer.from("metadata"), 
            Metadata.PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(), 
            mint.toBuffer()],
            Metadata.PROGRAM_ID
          );
          return publicKey;
        }
    
    let pda = await getMetadataPDA(mint);
    let res = await Metadata.Metadata.fromAccountAddress(connection, account);
```

Consider that mint is a PublicKey, not a string.

Here is JSON structure of the returned values
https://docs.metaplex.com/token-metadata/Versions/v1.0.0/nft-standard

Answer (score 4):

Unsure if this fully addresses your issue, but one way that I've fetched metadata for all tokens in a wallet is by using the metaplex library:

```js
import { programs } from "@metaplex/js"

const tokenMetadata = programs.metadata.Metadata.findByOwnerV2(connection, walletPublicKey);

console.log(JSON.stringify(tokenMetadata));
```

Printing the tokenMetadata for this test wallet looks like the following:

```json
[
  {
    "pubkey": "HPswFDfXcmpvj6RSvJoiuTe6r1wGuwJe9HgzkfhpHKUc",
    "info": {
      "executable": false,
      "owner": {
        "_bn": "0b7065b1e3d17c45389d527f6b04c3cd58b86c731aa0fdb549b6d1bc03f82946"
      },
      "lamports": 5616720,
      "data": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
          4, 60, 149, 84, 75, 223, 131, 43, 238, 37, 212, 193, 171, 139, 29,
          162, 158, 45, 52, 157, 244, 236, 53, 189, 60, 118, 83, 187, 176, 3,
          87, 134, 164, 70, 147, 118, 78, 64, 38, 124, 25, 241, 242, 54, 51, 83,
          80, 221, 253, 4, 95, 165, 233, 112, 107, 151, 166, 96, 148, 162, 114,
          132, 111, 55, 68, 32, 0, 0, 0, 89, 111, 117, 114, 32, 67, 111, 108,
          108, 101, 99, 116, 105, 111, 110, 32, 35, 52, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 0,
          0, 0, 104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 97, 114, 119, 101, 97, 118,
          101, 46, 110, 101, 116, 47, 121, 57, 105, 54, 104, 50, 97, 107, 65,
          100, 80, 105, 90, 112, 98, 65, 45, 114, 65, 110, 57, 87, 97, 101, 68,
          110, 83, 76, 85, 73, 78, 84, 117, 106, 109, 69, 113, 101, 118, 72, 66,
          117, 48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 148, 111, 225, 158, 161, 28, 45, 38, 87,
          197, 46, 209, 25, 126, 164, 251, 66, 44, 245, 255, 202, 46, 123, 104,
          19, 136, 141, 79, 66, 188, 138, 134, 1, 0, 206, 203, 108, 109, 123,
          133, 164, 214, 142, 166, 98, 20, 48, 35, 184, 204, 119, 234, 128, 56,
          190, 152, 177, 103, 83, 12, 148, 233, 189, 70, 167, 39, 0, 100, 1, 1,
          1, 254, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        ]
      }
    },
    "data": {
      "key": 4,
      "updateAuthority": "55VXi3ANYmig6eP8oewpz5KFzzjyT87RiX4mw2bfjchy",
      "mint": "5kVxPxTbu9k4Yu6zUtBgJ4CYKo7whX3PyQDd12zpdjz3",
      "data": {
        "name": "Your Collection #4",
        "symbol": "",
        "uri": "https://arweave.net/y9i6h2akAdPiZpbA-rAn9WaeDnSLUINTujmEqevHBu0",
        "sellerFeeBasisPoints": 0,
        "creators": [
          {
            "address": "AzSHgm4CEQr3akEvh7AppmZw3oDYWunu18FoM61XRwA5",
            "verified": 1,
            "share": 0
          },
          {
            "address": "EvEttHAwkVks2s5zEZjoPNVDBkhumTyvLTvaD5JQ3XCJ",
            "verified": 0,
            "share": 100
          }
        ]
      },
      "primarySaleHappened": 1,
      "isMutable": 1
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

<sub>Migrating OP's solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> As of 12.18.2021, please now use
>
> ```
> import * as metadata from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";
> const nftsmetadata:metadata.MetadataData[] = await metadata.Metadata.findDataByOwner(connection, publicKey);
> ```